# How does Facebook Instant personalisation work?

Tags: facebook, cross-domain, security, xss

I just visited http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ and without me filling in any login form, it knew my identity, because I was logged on to facebook.

I have found out that Trip Advisor is part of a program Facebook are running called 'Instant Personalisation'.

My question is:  How does this work?  What is going on behind the scenes?  What is being sent by my browser, by what method (eg HTTP POST, iFrame, Ajax etc), and to who?

In particular, I had previously thought that the browsers' cross-domain-scripting security rules made this kind of thing impossible.  I thought that browsers would never let a script on exampleone.com communicate with exampletwo.com.

So how is it possible that tripadvisor.com can gain access to information that I originally sent to facebook.com?  How are they able to get around the cross-domain scripting rules?

PS - Please do not tell me that I can disable Facebook Instant Personalisation.  I already know I can opt out (on this page https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications).  This is a question about the technology that makes Instant Personalisation possible.

EDIT --

A few people have already commented that a request is sent to facebook to obtain my details.  I agree that this must be the case.  But What I'm asking, is **how** does this request get sent to facebook?  If I visit tripadvisor.com then I'm actively telling my browser to make a request to tripadvisor.com.  NOT to facebook.com.  And I thought that a script running on tripadvisor.com would be blocked by my browser from communicating with facebook.com.

I find this extremely unsettling. Presumably if tripadvisor knows my identity, then their servers could inform facebook servers of the pages I view.  In the specific case of tripadvistor and facebook I'm not too bothered about this. I suspect the data would just be used for better targeting the kind of the ads they show me. Harmless enough....

But if my online identity can be passed around between domains like this without me knowing, in a way I previously thought was impossible, then this means there could be other sites who are using this technology for malicious purposes. So I want to understand whats going on, and understand what exactly I'm exposed to.

Comment: Trip Advisor probably gets your facebook ID and sends it to FaceBook who then sends certain information about you to Trip Advisor. I don't know this for sure, though.

Comment: Sounds like some sort of central authentication to me.

Comment: Lee - Yes, but HOW does Trip Advisor get my facebook ID in the first place?  That's the question.  When I visit tripadvistor.com my browser won't send them my facebook.com cookie...  so how do they get my facebook ID?

Comment: I think it's similar to how Facebook's Javascript SDK authentication works. A request is sent to Facebook which sends back the authenticated user data. Because it goes through Facebook, session data is preserved and sent back to tripadvisor, although this time, with limited access to public information I suppose.

Comment: @BassemDy you said "A request is sent to Facebook". How? I didn't visit facebook.com. I didn't explicitly send a request to facebook.com.  And I thought cross-domain rules prevented a script on tripadvisor.com from sending a request to facebook.com. That's why I asked this question. It feels like they're doing something that shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Yes tripadvisor can. I can launch the OAuth authentication process without you pressing any button. Because tripadvisor is a partner of Facebook in the Instant Personalization program, no actual authentication happens, but Facebook returns the current authenticated user's public information to tripadvisor.

Comment: @BassemDy Again, you're just saying what you think happens, not explaining **how** it happens.  When I visit tripadvisor.com, my browser sends tripadvisor a request (and a tripadvisor.com cookie) then they send my browser an html file, possibly with scripts, and my browser executes the scripts.  At what point in that process is facebook involved? You say you can launch the OAuth process - well what does that entail?  what data is sent where, and by who?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a brief technical explanation about what happens behind the scenes:

When tripadvisor loads the page, it makes a request to Facebook highlighted below:

[image: Facebook Connect request from TripAdvisor]

The request contains a specific ID from tripadvisor and some parameters defining what to return. Facebook validates the request and returns what seems to be an access token to an application that only has access to your public information. This token is only given to their partners.

Your client is always allowed to make HTTP requests to external domains! It's how CDNs work and multiple other web implementations. When you retrieve an image from an external source which is not contained on the server that is serving you the page content you are currently browsing, this is an external request which does not violate cross domain policies.

The response from Facebook is contained in:

```
xd_arbiter.php?version=25
```

It's javascript code that is executed on the client side which I presume allows tripadvisor to retrieve your public information.

Tripadvisor doesn't really have to access your cookies or violate cross domain security measures, everything happens on the server side **on the Facebook front**. Once Facebook validates the **origin** of the request (i.e. making sure the domain belongs to one of its program partners), it serves the request with the needed data.

If you  try to access the URL outside tripadvisor's scope you get the following:

[image: Facebook request problem]

**Further Readings:**

1.3.2 Implicit Grant Flow from OAuth specification docs:

> The implicit grant is a simplified authorization code flow optimized
> for clients implemented in a browser using a scripting language such
> as JavaScript.  In the implicit flow, instead of issuing the client
> an authorization code, the client is issued an access token directly
> (as the result of the resource owner authorization).  The grant type
> is implicit as no intermediate credentials (such as an authorization
> code) are issued (and later used to obtain an access token).

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-28#page-8

Answer (score 2):

OK, thanks for your help with this @BassemDy - you gave me 90% of the answer, and I've just figured out the other 10% that I was missing.

I can see that it's possible for tripadvisor to make my browser send a request to facebook without breaking any cross-domain rules.  As BassemDy pointed out, this happens all the time, when you load images from an external domain, or load a shared script from some external domain like google maps etc...

What I couldn't see, was how it was possible for tripadvisor to make my browser send a request to facebook, which could then identify me.

Then the answer hit me.  Of course tripadvisor's scripts can't directly read my facebook cookie...  but when my browser makes the cross domain request to facebook, **my browser will send my facebook cookie to facebook**.  That was the part I was missing.

Then facebook can respond in some way which tripadvisor's script can read, and hence tripadvisor's script can determine my identity.

All that business with OAuth and tokens is just a way of making the above process secure.  Underneath it all, is the fact that tripadvisor can make me send my facebook cookie to facebook.

As a proof of concept, I ran the following test scripts on 2 different domains I control:

on domainone.com - login.php

```
<?php setcookie('yourname','Daniel Howard',0,'/');
exit;
```

on domainone.com - responder.php

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/javascript'); ?>
window.cookieFromDomainone = <?= json_encode($_COOKIE) ?>;
window.updateMe();
```

then on domaintwo.com - test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="identityFromDomainone"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.updateMe = function() {
        document.getElementById('identityFromDomainone').innerHTML = window.cookieFromDomainone.yourname;
    };
</script>
<script src="http://domainone.com/responder.php" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

First I visit domainone.com/login.php and it sets a cookie with my name in it.  Something similar to this would happen when you login to facebook.

Then I visit domaintwo.com/test.php

It has no way to read my domainone.com cookie.  But it makes my browser send a request to domainone.com and **my browser will send along my domainone.com cookie** with the request.  Then, in domainone.com/responder the cookie values are fed into some javascript which is returned, and executed on domaintwo.com.

The javascript that is executed makes my identity available on domaintwo.com.  And this is illustrated when my name appears in the p element.

I'm quite appalled at how easy it is to write code that would basically spit out users identities to any site that cared to ask for it.  I wonder how many poorly written attempts at single-sign-on are out there in the wild waiting to be exploited....  Hopefully this OAuth system that facebook and their pals are using is secure.

Answer (score 0):

I've a hunch this is closely related to [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) - perhaps it automatically checks for a currently logged-in token and then initiates OAuth login.

Comment: It checks **what** for a token?  The only thing tripadvisor gets from me, is a HTTP request from my browser, and possibly a tripadvisor.com cookie.  Facebook can't set values in my tripadvisor.com cookie, and tripadvisor can't read my facebook.com cookie.  So where can tripadvisor get a currently-logged-in token from?